# Implementation of a quadtree in java using recursion function for counting compressed numbers

Tags: java, recursion, quadtree

I faced "java.lang.StackOverflowError", while doing recursion method.

Basically, I am solving quad compression algorithm problem.

Problem is

> In `Solution` class, there is a `solution` method, then you will get `int[][] arr`.
>
> Return `int[] answer` put the numbers of `0` and `1`.
>
> All elemnts are `0` or `1`.
>
> This input data is 2-d array, and you have to do quad tree compression.
>
> If elements are same in one quad, merge the elements. Then, of course you only count 1.

```
example 1)
1100
1000
1001
1111

11|00
10|00
--+--
10|01
11|11

11|0
10|
--+--
10|01
11|11
```

> The third one can not be quad compressed any more.
>
> (If there is more, it is going to be compressed more like this.) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNmYa.png)
>
> The number of 0 is 4, 1 is 9. So, return `int[] arr = [4,9]`.

Here's my code below.
What i wanted to do is that, i split up `arr` using recursion whenever there is different element. But if all are same, pass the for-loop, then make `dupl arr`'s element true, except one element.

I don't get where stackoverflow is raised.

```java
class Solution {
    int[][] arr;
    boolean[][] dupl;
    public int[] solution(int[][] arr) {
        this.arr = arr;
        this.dupl = new boolean[arr.length][arr[0].length];
        int[] answer = new int[2];
        recurse(0, arr.length, 0, arr.length);
        
        for(int i = 0; i < dupl.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < dupl[0].length; j++) {
                if(dupl[i][j] == true) continue;
                if(arr[i][j] == 0) ++answer[0];
                else if(arr[i][j] == 1) ++answer[1];
            }
        }
        
        return answer;
    }
    
    private void recurse(int rowStart, int rowEnd, int colStart, int colEnd) {
        if(rowStart == rowEnd || colStart == colEnd) return;
        
        int target = arr[rowStart][colStart];
        for(int r = rowStart; r < rowEnd; ++r) {
            for(int c = colStart; c < colEnd; ++c) {
                if(target != arr[r][c]) {
                    recurse(rowStart, rowEnd/2, colStart, colEnd/2);
                    recurse(rowStart, rowEnd/2, colEnd/2, colEnd);
                    recurse(rowEnd/2, rowEnd, colStart, colEnd/2);
                    recurse(rowEnd/2, rowEnd, colEnd/2, colEnd);
                    break;
                }
                target = arr[r][c];
            }
        }
        
        for(int r = rowStart; r < rowEnd; ++r) {
            for(int c = colStart; c < colEnd; ++c) {
                dupl[r][c] = true;
            }
        }
        dupl[rowStart][colStart]=false;
    }
}
```

Here are testcases

```
input = [[1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
output = [4, 9]

input = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
output = [10, 15]
```

Comment: Please post a complete, runnable example which illustrates youe problem.

Comment: Your second loop increments `i` rather than `j`.

Comment: Have you used the debugger already and inspected the actual parameters at each call? Are they what you expect or are some of them off?

Comment: @knittl Thanks for your advice, I just got the answer. I will comment answer on this question for anyone to see this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is a sort of `Divide and Conquer problem`.

So, it is wrong part below, since you have to start from the center(average number) of between previous start and end, when dividing.

`recurse(rowStart, rowEnd/2, colStart, colEnd/2);` will be `recurse(rowStart, (rowStart+rowEnd)/2, colStart, (colStart+colEnd)/2);`

```
                    recurse(rowStart, rowEnd/2, colStart, colEnd/2);
                    recurse(rowStart, rowEnd/2, colEnd/2, colEnd);
                    recurse(rowEnd/2, rowEnd, colStart, colEnd/2);
                    recurse(rowEnd/2, rowEnd, colEnd/2, colEnd);
```

The answer is :

```
class Solution {
    int[][] arr;
    boolean[][] dupl;
    public int[] solution(int[][] arr) {
        this.arr = arr;
        this.dupl = new boolean[arr.length][arr[0].length];
        int[] answer = new int[2];
        recurse(0, arr.length, 0, arr.length);
        
        for(int i = 0; i < dupl.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < dupl[0].length; j++) {
                if(dupl[i][j] == true) continue;
                if(arr[i][j] == 0) ++answer[0];
                else if(arr[i][j] == 1) ++answer[1];
            }
        }
        return answer;
    }
    
    private void recurse(int rowStart, int rowEnd, int colStart, int colEnd) {
        
        int target = arr[rowStart][colStart];
        for(int r = rowStart; r < rowEnd; ++r) {
            for(int c = colStart; c < colEnd; ++c) {
                if(target != arr[r][c]) {
                    recurse(rowStart, (rowStart+rowEnd)/2, colStart, (colStart+colEnd)/2);
                    recurse(rowStart, (rowStart+rowEnd)/2, (colStart+colEnd)/2, colEnd);
                    recurse((rowStart+rowEnd)/2, rowEnd, colStart, (colStart+colEnd)/2);
                    recurse((rowStart+rowEnd)/2, rowEnd, (colStart+colEnd)/2, colEnd);
                    return;
                }
                target = arr[r][c];
            }
        }
        
        for(int r = rowStart; r < rowEnd; ++r) {
            for(int c = colStart; c < colEnd; ++c) {
                dupl[r][c] = true;
            }
        }
        dupl[rowStart][colStart]=false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the difference exactly? Make it easy for future readers

Comment: @knittl The wrong part is calling recursion for splitting up. I wrote like this: `rowEnd/2`. But It should be like this: `(start+end)/2`. Cuz we have to divide half every single time. But i was confused, then i divided by 2. I edited this. Thanks.